# Error while creating table in Python Sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am running some query and I want to store the output of the query as new table. I am using Jupyter notebook where I have connected to a sqlite database which has the table I am using in the query.

```
sql2="""

create table sales_fact_unique  as
(
 with min_leads as 
 ( 
  select LeadId, min(BookingCreateDate)as FirstBookingDate
  from 
   sales_fact
    where GrossRevenue <>0
  group by
   LeadId
) 

 select a.LeadId, a.FirstBookingDate, b.ArrivalDate,
  b.DepartureDate,b.DealWonSalesPersonId,
  b.GrossRevenue,b.EngineFromFinalURL,b.CampaignFromFinalUrl
 from 
  min_leads as a
inner join 
 (select * from sales_fact where grossrevenue <>0 ) as b
 on a.leadid=b.leadid 
 and a.FirstBookingDate=b.BookingCreateDate
)
;

"""


conn.execute(sql2)
conn.commit()
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
<ipython-input-42-bc72021206b2> in <module>()
     45 
     46 
---> 47 c.execute(sql2)
     48 conn.commit()
     49 

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Any idea?

Comment: You really should use a ORM such as sqlalchemy. It will make your life so much simpler.

Comment: Any suggestions how to use that with sqlite?

Comment: You have the correct amount of opening and closing `()` symbols, but I think you need an extra closing one and opening one somewhere.

Comment: @Manish its not really something I can sum up in a post. It works the same with all versions of sql. Read the docs, they are really good and will be well with your time

Comment: The error is only coming when I use create table syntax. Its not there without that. But I do need to create a new table. And am not sure what is wrong here. Everything matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREATE TABLE ... AS ...](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) requires a query, not a subquery, so you have to remove the outermost pair of parentheses:

```sql
> CREATE TABLE t AS (SELECT 1);
Error: near "(": syntax error
> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT 1;
```